# Do I need a physical phone to test run the build from android source or can do it in emulator?

Tags: emulation, android

I am now downloading the android source code in ubuntu 10.10.

Just wanted to be sure that, I can build the OS from the source and test run it in the emulator just like any other Android application I run in emulator?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to, since the emulator counts as a connected device.

BUT chances are it probably wont work on very many phones, if any. Since all the phones are slightly different.

For instance a droid rom wont load properly on my nexus one and vice versa.

Comment: what is a ROM? When I build images from sources, is it?

Comment: A ROM stands for Read Only Memory and is basically the OS, so yes.